# Sorting a key value pair list in shell script

Tags: shell

I have a list in txt file as below 
a 2 
b 3 
c 1 
d 7 
e 2

I need to write a script that will arrange the list in descending order of the value as below 
d 7 
b 3 
a 2 
e 2 
c 1

I tried to sort this, but it sorts alphabetically, but doesn't sort by the second column value.

Could anyone please suggest me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sort -k 2r file`

`-k 2r` to sort in reverse using the second column.

Comment: This sorts the `a 2` and `e 2` lines incorrectly. Use `sort -k 2r` to fix that by limiting the reverse sort to the second field instead of every field/the whole line.

Comment: Oh you're right! I'm updating my answer. Thank you!

Comment: If I have a-2 and b-12, then this sorts by a-2 and b-12, but I want it to be b-12, a-2. I just got the hint from your answer and found that if I add -n then it sorts considering the above condition as well.